# Calculating the mass of the Earth atmosphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The density of air ρ is given by:

$\rho(r)=\rho_0e^{-c(r-R)}$ for $R\le r\le \infty$

where $R = 6380\text{ km}$, $\rho_0 = 1,225 \:\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, $c=\frac{\ln10}{17\text{ km}}$

I want to calculate the mass of the atmosphere

mass $m=\iiint\rho$ $dV$ = $\int_V\rho(r)\, dV$

Because the volume  $V(r) = {4 \over 3} \pi r^3 = {d V(r) \over dr} = 4 \pi r^2$

So we get after that:

$4\pi\int_R^\infty \rho(r)*r^2\,dr$ = $4\pi\int_{6380}^\infty 1,225*e^{\frac{-\ln10}{17}(r-6380)}*r^2\,dr$ $= \infty$

This should give me $4,7*10^{18}$kg but I don't get this answer.

Comment: Have you reviewed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688711/calculate-the-mass-of-the-earths-atmosphere-give-the-density-of-air) question?

Comment: Yes I have, but that question does not answer my question

Comment: In the line starting with "Because" the second = should be a comma

Comment: The integral you have at the end does not actually diverge. Anyway, remember to use the units consistently (you switch between metres and kilometres):
$$4\pi \int_{6380000}^{\infty} 1.225\cdot e^{-\frac{\ln(10)}{17000}(r-6380000)}\cdot r^2~dr$$
Or alternatively:
$$4\pi \int_{6380}^{\infty} 1.225\times 10^9 \cdot e^{-\frac{\ln(10)}{17}(r-6380)}\cdot r^2~dr$$
Computing this should give you the right answer.

Comment: To clarify your question, this is an estimate for the mass of the earths atmosphere based on the assumption the earth's atmosphere is dry. In addition the earth is approximated by perfect sphere of uniform density and uniform surface temperature and pressure, with tidal distortions due to gravitational forces from the sun and moon being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can rescale your integral to $\int e^{-r}r^2 \ dr$ which converges.  You can integrate it by parts twice, differentiating the $r^2$ term and integrating the exponential.  This [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E2e%5E%28-x%29) $-e^{-r}(x^2+2x+2)+C$